# Cannot use case and exists in an sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do:

```
select
case when exists (id) then id else 'n/a' end as id
from mytable
where id="35";
```

but I have some error or the other that pops up. What am I doing wrong, or is this just not doable?

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id) then id else 'n/a' end as id from mytable where id="35"' at line 2 */
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select case when id = 35 then id else 'n/a' end as id
from mytable
order by case when id = 35 then 1 else 2 end 
limit 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86dda/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little trick,

```
SELECT  COALESCE(b.id, 'n/a') id
FROM    
        (
            SELECT 35 id -- the id you want to search
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN mytable b
            ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   a.id = 35
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4494/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use Sub Query like this:

```
SELECT 
  TABEL1.Id, 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID)
       THEN 'TRUE' 
       ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS NewFiled  
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Can you post an example like the rest?

Comment: All of this happens using only a single table called `mytable`.

Comment: I like your answer, but I'm having a tuff time getting it to work. No just that, I cannot figure where the `where` clause goes.

Answer (score 0):

If all `id` values are unique:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = 35),
    'n/a'
  ) AS id
;
```

If the column can have duplicates, just add LIMIT 1 to the end of the subquery:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = 35 LIMIT 1),
    'n/a'
  ) AS id
;
```